# Similarity measure of predicted football endsocre

Tags: prediction, validation, games

We have a betting game going on in our firm for the FIFA World Cup 2018. We have a simple system where you get 1 point for naming the correct winner or a draw and 3 points for getting the score right.

However, I would like to calculate the similarity between a particular prediction and the actual score. Or even the similarity of a predicted score between two people.

We were thinking of looking at the scores as points on a coordinate system and calculating distances between the points. But this of course does not take into a account that a 0:0 is less similar to 1:0 than 2:1 for example. Is there a measure out there? I can't seem to find any..

**EDIT:**

Apparently, I was not very clear in formulating my question. What I'm looking for is a similarity measure[*] for two game score outcomes. For two scores implying the same outcome (Eg. "Team2 wins"), one could simply use the inverse of a [2D Euclidean Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Two_dimensions). E.g comparing the scores (see image below)

- Score A 2:3
- Score B 3:4
- Score C 4:6

Similarities (inverse of euclidean distance)

- Similarity A-B: 0.71
- Similarity A-C: 0.27
- Similarity B-C: 0.45

But the whole thing becomes difficult when comparing scores with a small Euclidean distance, but different outcomes. Eg: 0:0 is closer to 0:1 than 0:0 is to 0:5. Before we try to reinvent the wheel: **Is there no such thing as a similarity measure for scores?**

[image]

[*] As an example: Similarity measures for trajectories include Dynamic time warping (DTW), Frechèt Distance, longest common subsequences (LCSS) and edit distance. See [Buchin et al., 2011](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772111000344)

Comment: Your example is not very clear :) 0-0 would get a score of zero while 1-0 would get a score of 1 if the outcome of the game is 2-1... If you mean that 1-0 for example is closer to 2-1 than 2-0 or 3-0... then a suggestion would be to award an additional point for guessing the goal difference right, or something of the sort... If you award an equal number of pts for two outcomes then this essentially means that these two outcomes are identical from your pt of view...

Comment: @byouness: Thank you for your comment. I've extended the example to be more clear.. I hope it helps.